# Silverlight - add tooltip to a rotated textblock

Tags: silverlight, xaml, rotation, tooltip

I have a TextBlock which is rotated at 90 degrees in the Silverlight XAML:

```
<TextBlock Name="txbPW" Text="West">
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
          <RotateTransformAngle="90" />
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
</TextBlock>
```

I want to add a tooltip (not rotated) to it. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's your problem? Do you want to show the tooltip rotated too?? Or don't?? Or are you just asking to add a tooltip to a textblock???

If you only want to add a tooltip to a textblock you have to do something like this:

```
<TextBlock Name="txbPW" Text="West">
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
          <RotateTransformAngle="90" />
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
          <ToolTip Content="ToolTip"></ToolTip>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

http://bouncetadiss.blogspot.com.es/2010/02/tooltip-for-textblock-in-silverlight.html